# Showing a image with random filename and type in page

Tags: c#, html, .net-core

I have used this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0 to upload images from user to my own location. This is working fine, and when the user uploads the files I get something like "friIjfdls.m4s". It also works fine downloading them.

Just to give a short explanation of the process:

- User selects images on his computer and uploads them
- I check that it is a image
- I give the file a random name before saving it to the wwwroot folder
- In DB I store the "correct" name

So when the user wants do download it I retrieve the image and the correct name (from db) and "merge" them.

But now I came out for a problem because I also want to show the images on my page. Is that possible? So I cant use the same process as "download file" because that makes the server to a lot of stuff before sending it to the user and it automatically starts downloading. But I just want to show the image as a static(?) image on the page. How can I do that?

Comment: showing an image in a page is exactly the same as sending to a client via dowload. (the browser is a http client after all)

Comment: I dont quite understand. What should I set as source of <img>-tag? Or is it any other way to show images?

Comment: you can encode the image as base64 https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up doing it this way:

```
        FileStream fileStream = ResourcesRepository.GetFileByUrl(imagePath);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
        fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
        this.ImageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

And this worked. Thank you @J.Salas for the direction.